# MP3 won't stream with JMF

Tags: java, audio, streaming, mp3, jmf

Basic idea is to access .mp3 file and send it through RTP stream to other client, who will want to play that song.

Here is RTPServer.java, which I found online and modified it to my liking.

```
    package server;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import javax.media.rtp.*;
import javax.media.rtp.rtcp.*;
import javax.media.*;
import javax.media.protocol.*;
import javax.media.control.*;

public class RTPServer implements ControllerListener, Runnable {
    private boolean realized = false;
    private boolean configured = false;
    private String ipAddress;
    Processor p;
    MediaLocator src;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        RTPServer rtp = new RTPServer("192.168.1.101", "04 - Blue.mp3");
        Thread t = new Thread(rtp);
        t.start();
    }

    public RTPServer(String ip, String song) {
        ipAddress = ip;
 String srcFile = "Muzika\\" + song;
 src = new MediaLocator("file:" + srcFile);

    }

    private void setTrackFormat(Processor p) {
 // Get the tracks from the processor
 TrackControl [] tracks = p.getTrackControls();
 // Do we have atleast one track?
 if (tracks == null || tracks.length < 1) {
     System.out.println("Couldn't find tracks in processor");
     System.exit(1);
 }

 // Set the output content descriptor to RAW_RTP
 // This will limit the supported formats reported from
 // Track.getSupportedFormats to only valid RTP formats.
 ContentDescriptor cd = new ContentDescriptor(ContentDescriptor.RAW_RTP);
 p.setContentDescriptor(cd);

 Format supported[];
 Format chosen;
 boolean atLeastOneTrack = false;

 // Program the tracks.
 for (int i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
     Format format = tracks[i].getFormat();
            System.out.println("Trenutni format je " +format.getEncoding());
     if (tracks[i].isEnabled()) {
  supported = tracks[i].getSupportedFormats();
  for (int n = 0; n < supported.length; n++)
      System.out.println("Supported format: " + supported[n]);

  // We've set the output content to the RAW_RTP.
  // So all the supported formats should work with RTP.
  // We'll just pick the first one.

  if (supported.length > 0) {
      chosen = supported[0]; // this is where I tried changing formats
      tracks[i].setFormat(chosen);
      System.err.println("Track " + i + " is set to transmit as: " +chosen);
      atLeastOneTrack = true;
  } else
      tracks[i].setEnabled(false);
     } else
  tracks[i].setEnabled(false);
 }
    }

    private void transmit(Processor p) {
 try {
     DataSource output = p.getDataOutput();
     PushBufferDataSource pbds = (PushBufferDataSource) output;
     RTPManager rtpMgr = RTPManager.newInstance();
     SessionAddress localAddr, destAddr;
     SendStream sendStream;
     int port = 42050;
     SourceDescription srcDesList[];
     localAddr = new SessionAddress( InetAddress.getLocalHost(), port);
     InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
     destAddr = new SessionAddress( ipAddr, port);
     rtpMgr.initialize(localAddr);
     rtpMgr.addTarget(destAddr);
     sendStream = rtpMgr.createSendStream(output, 0);
     sendStream.start();
     System.err.println( "Created RTP session: " + ipAddress + " " + port);
     p.start();
 } catch(Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
    }

    public synchronized void controllerUpdate(ControllerEvent evt) {
 if (evt instanceof RealizeCompleteEvent) {
     realized = true;
 } else  if (evt instanceof ConfigureCompleteEvent) {
     configured = true;
 } else if (evt instanceof EndOfMediaEvent) {
     System.exit(0);
 } else {
     // System.out.println(evt.toString());
 }
    }

    public void run() {

 try {
     p = Manager.createProcessor(src);
     p.addControllerListener(this);
     p.configure();
     while (! configured) {
  try {
      Thread.currentThread().sleep(100L);;
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      // ignore
  }
     }

     setTrackFormat(p);
     p.setContentDescriptor(new ContentDescriptor(ContentDescriptor.RAW_RTP));

     p.realize();
     while (! realized) {
  try {
      Thread.currentThread().sleep(100L);;
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      // ignore
  }
     }
     transmit(p);

 } catch(Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     System.exit(1);
 }
    }
}
```

And here is receiving end, RTPClient:

```
    package client;


import javax.media.*;

public class RTPClient implements ControllerListener, Runnable {

    Player p;
    MediaLocator src;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RTPClient rtp = new RTPClient("192.168.1.100");
        Thread t = new Thread(rtp);
        t.start();

    }

    public RTPClient(String ip) {
 String srcUrl = "rtp://" + ip + ":42050/audio/1";
 DataSink sink;
 src = new MediaLocator(srcUrl);
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
     p = Manager.createPlayer(src);
     p.addControllerListener(this);
     p.start();
 } catch(Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     System.exit(1);
 }
    }

    public synchronized void controllerUpdate(ControllerEvent evt) {
 if (evt instanceof EndOfMediaEvent) {
     System.exit(0);
 } else {
     System.out.println(evt.toString());
 }
    }
}
```

I figured, it successfully sends the whatever file I choose, but when I send .mp3, Client won't play it. I get:

```
    RTP Handler internal error:
javax.media.ControllerErrorEvent[source=com.sun.media.content.unknown.Handler@9ed927,message=Internal
module com.sun.media.BasicRendererModule@1386000: failed to handle a data
format change!]
```

Interesting thing is, .wav is sent perfectly. So my guess was is the format set prior to sending. And I tried changing format to some other supported format, but then I get bunch of other errors.

```
    Failed to build a graph for the given custom options.
Failed to realize: com.sun.media.ProcessEngine@eee36c
  Cannot build a flow graph with the customized options:
    Unable to transcode format: mpegaudio, 48000.0 Hz, 16-bit, Stereo, LittleEndian, Signed, 20000.0 frame rate, FrameSize=11264 bits
      to: ULAW/rtp, 8000.0 Hz, 8-bit, Stereo
      outputting to: RAW/RTP
Error: Unable to realize com.sun.media.ProcessEngine@eee36c
```

Finally, I opened JMStudio (the built-in app for sending/receiving media streams in JMF), and when I try to stream .mp3, I get exact same error as when running my app. JMF is set up fine, I checked PATH and CLASSPATH, also I installed mp3plugin which is also setup fine. Everything seems fine, but it just doesn't work! At least .mp3 is not.
So, how can I make .mp3 "go to the other end"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved.

All I had to do is add these lines in constructor for sender/receiver.

```
Format input1 = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.MPEGLAYER3);
Format input2 = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.MPEG);
Format output = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.LINEAR);
PlugInManager.addPlugIn(
        "com.sun.media.codec.audio.mp3.JavaDecoder",
        new Format[]{input1, input2},
        new Format[]{output},
        PlugInManager.CODEC);
```

Might help somebody else with this problem :)
Still don't know why JMStudio isn't working... Not that I care anymore.

Comment: Does the client/server have to be on differnt ips or do they both work on the one i.e bothwork of localhost/

Answer (score 0):

My environment cannot detect the newly added plugin. I would have to hardcode the codec into the track. It works but the mp3 is cluttering. .wav is perfectly fine though.

```
javax.media.Codec codec = (javax.media.Codec) (Class.forName(plugins.get(0)).newInstance());
    com.sun.media.codec.audio.mp3.JavaDecoder decoder = new com.sun.media.codec.audio.mp3.JavaDecoder();
    Codec[] cc = new Codec[2];
    cc[0] = codec;
    cc[1] = decoder;
    try {
        tracks[0].setCodecChain(cc);
    } catch (UnsupportedPlugInException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NotConfiguredError e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple things to do to make the code in question works:

1. put [mp3plugin.jar](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-137625.html) in the classpath. It is a mp3 plugin for JMF. You may find it online.
2. put the following code in the main method to register the newly added plugin.

   ```
   Format input1 = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.MPEGLAYER3);
   Format input2 = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.MPEG);
   Format output = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.LINEAR);
   PlugInManager.addPlugIn(
           "com.sun.media.codec.audio.mp3.JavaDecoder",
           new Format[]{input1, input2},
           new Format[]{output},
           PlugInManager.CODEC);
   ```
3. set the track format to AduioFormat.DVI_RTP in the RTPServer.java to convert your mp3 music  to a format that RTPClient can play.

Before

```
if (supported.length > 0) {
      chosen = supported[0]; // this is where I tried changing formats
      tracks[i].setFormat(chosen);
      System.err.println("Track " + i + " is set to transmit as: " +chosen);
      atLeastOneTrack = true;
  } else
```

After ( replace "chosen" with "new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.DVI_RTP)" )

```
if (supported.length > 0) {
      chosen = supported[0]; // this is where I tried changing formats
      tracks[i].setFormat(new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.DVI_RTP));
      atLeastOneTrack = true;
  } else
```

Then everything should work just fine.

Here is my RTPServer

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;    
import javax.media.rtp.*;
import javax.media.rtp.rtcp.*;
import javax.media.*;
import javax.media.protocol.*;
import javax.media.control.*;
import javax.media.format.AudioFormat;

public class RTPServerMP3 implements ControllerListener {
    private String ipAddress;
    Processor p;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoProcessorException, IOException {
        Format input1 = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.MPEGLAYER3);
        Format input2 = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.MPEG);
        Format output = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.LINEAR);
        PlugInManager.addPlugIn(
                "com.sun.media.codec.audio.mp3.JavaDecoder",
                new Format[]{input1, input2},
                new Format[]{output},
                PlugInManager.CODEC);
        RTPServerMP3 rtp = new RTPServerMP3("192.168.1.86");
        rtp.p = Manager.createProcessor(new MediaLocator((new File( "roar_of_future.mp3")).toURL()));
        rtp.p.addControllerListener(rtp);
        rtp.p.configure();
    }
    public RTPServerMP3(String ip) throws MalformedURLException {
        ipAddress = ip;
    }
    private void setTrackFormat(Processor p) {
        // Get the tracks from the processor
        TrackControl[] tracks = p.getTrackControls();
        // Do we have atleast one track?
        if (tracks == null || tracks.length < 1) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't find tracks in processor");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        // Set the output content descriptor to RAW_RTP
        // This will limit the supported formats reported from
        // Track.getSupportedFormats to only valid RTP formats.
        ContentDescriptor cd = new ContentDescriptor(ContentDescriptor.RAW_RTP);
        p.setContentDescriptor(cd);
        Format supported[];
        Format chosen;
        boolean atLeastOneTrack = false;
        // Program the tracks.
        for (int i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
            Format format = tracks[i].getFormat();
            System.out.println("seeing format " + format.getEncoding() + " for track " + i);
            if (tracks[i].isEnabled()) {
                supported = tracks[i].getSupportedFormats();
                for (int n = 0; n < supported.length; n++)
                    System.out.println("Supported format: " + supported[n]);
                // We've set the output content to the RAW_RTP.
                // So all the supported formats should work with RTP.
                // We'll just pick the first one.
                if (supported.length > 0) {
                    chosen = supported[0]; // this is where I tried changing formats
                    tracks[i].setFormat(new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.DVI_RTP));
                    System.err.println("Track " + i + " is set to transmit as: " + chosen);
                    atLeastOneTrack = true;
                } else
                    tracks[i].setEnabled(false);
            } else
                tracks[i].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    private void transmit(Processor p) {
        try {
            DataSource output = p.getDataOutput();
            PushBufferDataSource pbds = (PushBufferDataSource) output;
            RTPManager rtpMgr = RTPManager.newInstance();
            SessionAddress localAddr, destAddr;
            SendStream sendStream;
            int port = 49150;
            SourceDescription srcDesList[];
            localAddr = new SessionAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), port/2+10);
            InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
            destAddr = new SessionAddress(ipAddr, port);
            rtpMgr.initialize(localAddr);
            rtpMgr.addTarget(destAddr);
            sendStream = rtpMgr.createSendStream(output, 0);
            sendStream.start();
            System.err.println("Created RTP session: " + ipAddress + " " + port);
            p.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void controllerUpdate(ControllerEvent evt) {
        if (evt instanceof RealizeCompleteEvent) {
            transmit(p);
        } else if (evt instanceof ConfigureCompleteEvent) {
            setTrackFormat(p);
            p.setContentDescriptor(new ContentDescriptor(ContentDescriptor.RAW_RTP));
            p.realize();
        } else if (evt instanceof EndOfMediaEvent) {
            System.exit(0);
        } 
    }
}
```

Here is my RTPClient

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.media.*;

public class RTPClientMP3  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoPlayerException, CannotRealizeException, IOException {
        String srcUrl = "rtp://192.168.1.86:49150/audio/1";
        MediaLocator src = new MediaLocator(srcUrl);
        Player player = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(src);
        player.start();

    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is updated with working code (RTPServer and RTPClient). Please take a look and let me know the exact part that you don't understand, if there is any.