# Streaming .wav with jmf and rtp protocol

Tags: java, audio-streaming, rtp, jmf

I would like to implement a simple Client Server model based on jmf and rtp to access .wav file and play it.

I refer to this discussion [MP3 won't stream with JMF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839747/mp3-wont-stream-with-jmf)
where the problem was with .mp3 and so I tryed it with my .wav without success because I've problem with RTP Session Managaer.

A first question is if I have to run RTPClient and RTPServer with two different machines, because until now I have RTPServer and RTPClient on the same pc in the same project and in package only different.

Is it a problem? Is there a way to try the client-server model on localhost for example?

Thanks in advance for your attention!